# All DNS queries to Bind9 server shows gateway IP instead of actual clients after switching to Linksys AC5400

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, centos7

On CentOS 7, instead of the actual client IP, the gateway IP is now showing up in Bind9 server logs.

The primary DNS server is 192.168.10.1 and the secondary is 192.168.10.2. The gateway is 192.168.1.1.

Even the queries from the secondary DNS, which's on the same subnet, show up as from the router/gateway. The zone transfers queries were sent from 192.168.10.2, but the log shows 192.168.1.1 instead.

IPv6 has been disabled on the DNS servers, but there's no way to disable it on the router.

```
31-Mar-2017 02:55:19.482 client 192.168.1.17#4394 (w.sharethis.com): view internal: query: w.sharethis.com IN A + (192.168.10.1)
31-Mar-2017 02:55:19.483 client 192.168.1.17#6929 (w.sharethis.com): view internal: query: w.sharethis.com IN AAAA + (192.168.10.1)
31-Mar-2017 02:55:19.670 client 192.168.1.17#28991 (www.sharethis.com): view internal: query: www.sharethis.com IN A + (192.168.10.1)
31-Mar-2017 02:55:19.671 client 192.168.1.17#23843 (www.sharethis.com): view internal: query: www.sharethis.com IN AAAA + (192.168.10.1)
31-Mar-2017 02:55:29.430 client 66.249.66.237#59407 (www.firmr.esources.com): view external: query: www.firmr.example.com IN A - (192.168.10.1)
31-Mar-2017 02:55:34.596 client 192.168.1.1#63655 (clients4.google.com): view internal: query: clients4.google.com IN A + (192.168.10.1)
```

Also for zone transfer:

```
31-Mar-2017 02:11:49.215 client 192.168.1.1#44467 (example1.com): view internal: transfer of 'example1.com/IN': AXFR started
31-Mar-2017 02:11:49.215 client 192.168.1.1#44467 (example1.com): view internal: transfer of 'example1.com/IN': AXFR ended
31-Mar-2017 02:12:21.626 client 192.168.1.1#36090 (example1.com): view internal: transfer of 'example1.com/IN': AXFR started
31-Mar-2017 02:12:21.626 client 192.168.1.1#36090 (example1.com): view internal: transfer of 'example1.com/IN': AXFR ended
31-Mar-2017 02:13:03.715 client 192.168.1.1#49586 (example1.com): view internal: transfer of 'example1.com/IN': AXFR started
31-Mar-2017 02:13:03.715 client 192.168.1.1#49586 (example1.com): view internal: transfer of 'example1.com/IN': AXFR ended
31-Mar-2017 02:41:27.469 client 192.168.1.1#50906 (example1.com): view internal: transfer of 'example1.com/IN': AXFR started
31-Mar-2017 02:41:27.470 client 192.168.1.1#50906 (example1.com): view internal: transfer of 'example1.com/IN': AXFR ended
31-Mar-2017 02:41:37.311 client 192.168.1.1#56073 (example2.com): view internal: transfer of 'example2.com/IN': AXFR started
31-Mar-2017 02:41:37.311 client 192.168.1.1#56073 (example2.com): view internal: transfer of 'example2.com/IN': AXFR ended
```

Traceroute:

```
traceroute to 192.168.10.1 (192.168.10.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  gateway (192.168.1.1)  0.393 ms  0.395 ms  0.297 ms
 2  ns1.example.com (192.168.10.1)  0.872 ms !X  0.844 ms !X  0.795 ms !X
```

Comment: Where are subnets masks and interfaces?

Comment: Subnet mask: 255.255.0.0
Gateway: 192.168.1.1
The machine is a vSphere 6.5 VM on a single VMNetwork. Does it have anything to do with the vSwitch?
Port 53 forwarded to 192.168.10.1, but it shouldn't matter, since we are dealing with internal network.
The problem did not exist with a Linksys E3200 router on DD-WRT with no advanced routing what-so-ever.

Comment: Also the pings to the DNS servers are replied from the gateway.

Comment: I think, there's a connection issue. Are you sure that dns servers were connected to local network? Check it by MAC addresses​ by ping via arp protocol `arping -I local_network_interface 192.168.1.1` from dns server. Is MAC address the same as on router's local network interface?

Comment: Yes they are.

`ARPING 192.168.1.1 from 192.168.10.1 ens160
Unicast reply from 192.168.1.1 [AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF]  0.988ms
Unicast reply from 192.168.1.1 [AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF]  0.752ms
Unicast reply from 192.168.1.1 [AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF]  0.800ms`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traceroute has the most glaring problem:

```
traceroute to 192.168.10.1 (192.168.10.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  gateway (192.168.1.1)  0.393 ms  0.395 ms  0.297 ms
 2  ns1.example.com (192.168.10.1)  0.872 ms !X  0.844 ms !X  0.795 ms !X
```

This is simply wrong.  You shouldn't be going thru a layer 3 device (router) to reach another element on the same IP subnet.  Layer 2 (switch) maybe, but it wouldn't show up in a traceroute.  Double check your subnet mask on `192.168.10.2` to ensure it is what it needs to be.  Maybe look at 192.168.1.17 (from the query logs) as an example - that one is working correctly.

Failing that, please post the output of `netstat -rn` (or `ip route`) from `192.168.10.2`.  It might also be helpful to know how your vSwitch is configured (VLANs)

Comment: Thanks! I'm using CentOS 7 and Ubuntu 16.04 at the same time. I thought I had set the net mask in CentOS hosts to 255.255.0.0 because that's what I always set Ubuntu hosts to. Turns out, I didn't, since unlike Ubuntu, CentOS uses prefix instead of netmask. When I was using the DD-WRT router, I manually set the global netmask to 255.255.0.0, but the setting's unavailable in the AC5400 with the stock firmware. After I set the prefix to 16, the traffic is now routed correctly. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: No problem - glad it worked out.  Out of curiosity, did you notice your external view returned a 192.168.x.x address? (+1 for having views setup correctly btw)

Comment: Yes. It's a web server on CentOS that also had the prefix misconfig. It's been resolved as well. Thanks!